# How do I pass a list of values to a function expecting an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2012, initializer-list

In my program I want to pass a few variables into a function and have that function run a for loop to write the data to console.

This is my code:

```
void WriteValue(int[] arr)
{
    for(auto c : arr)
        std::cout<<arr<<std::endl;
}

int main() 
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    int c = 3;

    WriteValue(a,b,c);

    return 0;
}
```

I know this would work in C# with params, but I don't have that option. How do I get this to run in C++?

Comment: I don't see anything here with `unsigned` type.  Are you looking for a variadic function, or perhaps `std::initializer_list<int>` ?

Comment: Just so you know, declaration follows use, so it would be `int* arr` or `int arr[]`, but then you couldn't use ranged-for since a pointer doesn't carry the size with it.  And you wanted to send `c` to `cout`, not `arr`.

Comment: @BenVoigt Good to know. I'm not so concerned about the for loop though. I just needed something in there to test it. I'm more concerned about passing my values into my function.

Comment: You do understand that `WriteValue` as written above won't work, even if you passed it an actual array?

Comment: @Yakk I know. I wanted an example of what I was after. I knew the above wouldn't run in C++, but I do know it would run in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a very simple and flexible way:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void WriteValue(const T& arr)
{
    for(auto c : arr)
        std::cout << c << std::endl;
}

int main() 
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    int c = 3;

    WriteValue(std::array<int, 3>{a,b,c});
    // nicer C99 way: WriteValue((int[]){a,b,c});

    return 0;
}
```

If you only want to be able to pass a list of ints (and it has to be a brace-separated list, not an existing array), you can instead do

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

void WriteValue(const std::initializer_list<int>& arr)
{
    for(auto c : arr)
        std::cout << c << std::endl;
}

int main() 
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    int c = 3;

    WriteValue({a,b,c});

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, [VS2012 doesn't support this.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx#featurelist)  You can upgrade to Visual 2013 (the Express Edition and [Community Edition](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-community-vs.aspx) are both free), or you can use a helper variable:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void WriteValue(const T& arr)
{
    for(auto c : arr)
        std::cout << c << std::endl;
}

int main() 
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    int c = 3;

    int args[] = { a, b, c };
    WriteValue(args);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried both of those methods, but neither one seems to be working. When I try the first one it gives me an error on this line: `WriteValue((int[3]){a,b,c});`. It says it's expecting an expression. With the second one it says it initializer_list is undefined. Is that a C++ 11 library? If it is I don't think my laptop supports it.

Comment: @SyntaxIsEvil: Yes, `std::initializer_list` is part of C++11.  So is the ranged-for in your question.  If you need answers for a particular compiler, rather than standard C++, you need to say so in your question.

Comment: I didn't know about C++11 until today so I don't know what is and isn't supported on my current version. I don't know what version of C++ I am currently using. I have been using that for in other parts of my code and it has been working without any issues. For standard C++ how would I solve my current problem?

Comment: @SyntaxIsEvil: Right now, C++14 is "Standard C++".  You almost certainly are using something older, if the second program in my answer isn't working for you.  What is the name of the compiler you are using?

Comment: I don't quite know what you mean by compiler. If it's the program I'm using to write and run my code I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: @SyntaxIsEvil: Visual Studio is an "integrated development environment" which means it has an editor, compiler, and debugger.  (So yes, that's what I was looking for)

Comment: To standardize the first code sample, change `(int[3])` to `std::array<int, 3>`

Comment: In the second example you can change `<int>` to be a template parameter .. the second example would be my preferred solution as the call syntax is simple

Comment: I upgraded to 2013 Express and now have initializer_list so these examples work. Thank you very much for your help. I know it will help me a lot more now that I have upgraded as well.